# How to block bots with nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a Rails app running on nginx on the aws elastic beanstalk platform. I've checked the nginx/access.log and found a number of suspicious GET requests like so:

```
SUSPICIOUS_URL == '#m. #face #book #.com'

172.31.17.148 - - [24/Jul/2016:04:02:37 +0000] "GET /bisnis/read/2439204/beredar-di-medsos-bi-bantah-keluarkan-uang-pecahan-rp-200-ribu HTTP/1.1" 301 5 
"http://SUSPICIOUS_URL/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-E700H Build/LMY47X; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2
704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/86.0.0.19.69;]" "175.141.68.34"

172.31.17.148 - - [24/Jul/2016:04:02:37 +0000] "GET /bisnis/read/2439204/beredar-di-medsos-bi-bantah-keluarkan-uang-pecahan-rp-200-ribu HTTP/1.1" 301 5 
"http://SUSPICIOUS_URL/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-E700H Build/LMY47X; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2
704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/86.0.0.19.69;]" "175.141.68.34"

172.31.17.148 - - [24/Jul/2016:04:02:37 +0000] "GET /bisnis/read/2439204/beredar-di-medsos-bi-bantah-keluarkan-uang-pecahan-rp-200-ribu HTTP/1.1" 301 5 
"http://SUSPICIOUS_URL/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-E700H Build/LMY47X; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2
704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/86.0.0.19.69;]" "175.141.68.34"

172.31.17.148 - - [24/Jul/2016:04:02:37 +0000] "GET /bisnis/read/2439204/beredar-di-medsos-bi-bantah-keluarkan-uang-pecahan-rp-200-ribu HTTP/1.1" 301 5 
"http://SUSPICIOUS_URL/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-E700H Build/LMY47X; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2
704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/86.0.0.19.69;]" "175.141.68.34"

172.31.17.148 - - [24/Jul/2016:04:02:38 +0000] "GET /bisnis/read/2439204/beredar-di-medsos-bi-bantah-keluarkan-uang-pecahan-rp-200-ribu HTTP/1.1" 301 5 
"http://SUSPICIOUS_URL/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-E700H Build/LMY47X; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2
704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/86.0.0.19.69;]" "175.141.68.34"

172.31.17.148 - - [24/Jul/2016:04:02:38 +0000] "GET /bisnis/read/2439204/beredar-di-medsos-bi-bantah-keluarkan-uang-pecahan-rp-200-ribu HTTP/1.1" 301 5 
"http://SUSPICIOUS_URL/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-E700H Build/LMY47X; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2
704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/86.0.0.19.69;]" "175.141.68.34"

172.31.17.148 - - [24/Jul/2016:04:02:38 +0000] "GET /bisnis/read/2439204/beredar-di-medsos-bi-bantah-keluarkan-uang-pecahan-rp-200-ribu HTTP/1.1" 301 5 
"http:/SUSPICIOUS_URL/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-E700H Build/LMY47X; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2
704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/86.0.0.19.69;]" "175.141.68.34"
```

I'm fairly certain that these are bots, how do I block these suspicious requests with nginx?

---

Edit:

Apparently this is a practice called referral spamming. Read more here. https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Referer_spam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a Samsung Galaxy using outdated dns-entry for m.facebook.com ;-)

Well, if you take a look at your access.log you will find a lot of requests like `/pma`, `/webadmin`, `/admin/config.php`, `/w00tw00t`, `/vtigercrm` and so on. It seems that there are a few bots checking for old / vulnerable versions of well-known opensource software like phpmyadmin, wordpress or something else.

Since we didn't like that very much, we tried to keep them out.
First time, we only added a few locations to our nginx-config, sending an error 404 on requests which matched an entry from a manually-filled list. That was nice to confuse them but didn't really decrease the amount of "bad requests". Later on, we moved the list to "fail2ban". Whenever a GET-request appeared on access.log with one of our predefined URIs, the client IP was blocked for 48 hours by iptables. since they couldn't reach our server anymore, that helped very much.
You only need to install fail2ban, add a filter (on debian at /etc/fil2an/filter.d/xxx.conf) with a simple list of regex values and add the filter to jail.conf.

For example, `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-bots.conf:`

```
[INCLUDES]

[Definition]
failregex =     ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/phpmyadmin/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/phpMyAdmin/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/pma/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/PMA/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/sqlmanager/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/phpmyadmin-?2/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/phpMyAdmin-?2/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/mysqlmanager/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/webadmin/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/php-my-admin/

                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/myadmin
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/MyAdmin
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/cgi-bin/
                ^<HOST> - .* "POST /?/%%
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /admin/config.php
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /idssvc/iesvc
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /vtigercrm/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /wstats/wstats
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /CluJaNul/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /bynazi/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /invoker/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET \\x
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /jmx-console/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /zecmd/
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /?/manager/html/upload

                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /w00tw00t
                ^<HOST> - .* "GET /muieblackcat

ignoreregex =
```

Added on `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`:

```
[nginx-bots] 
enable   = true
port     = http,https
filter   = nginx-bots
logpath  = /var/log/nginx/access.log*
maxretry = 1
bantime  = 172800
findtime = 86400
```

You also could think about another way to filter out those bots. If you add the status-code to nginx access log format you are able to set up the fail2ban/filter.conf to block users with more than 10 404-errors per minute - or somthing like that.

But you have to keep in mind, that it might block "good" users, if your fail2ban-configuration isn't good enough.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. I've done more research and apparently it's a practice called referral spamming. It seems like the blacklist is the way to go.

Comment: there is a spelling mistake on enable = true and this doesn't work... it should be enabled = true - i hope everything else is OK as I am going to use this code on my live site !